# Nest.js Passport.js Google conflicts with Apple

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, passport.js

I have created auth for application by google (passport-google-oauth20) and apple (passport-appleid). When i try to invoke GET google-sign-in, I have the following error

```
 [Nest] 987  - 07/22/2022, 9:49:18 AM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'callbackURL')
 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'callbackURL')
     at GoogleStrategy.OAuth2Strategy.authenticate (/home/node/app/node_modules/passport-appleid/lib/strategy.js:76:59)
     at attempt (/home/node/app/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:369:16)
     at authenticate (/home/node/app/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:370:7)
     at /home/node/app/node_modules/@nestjs/passport/dist/auth.guard.js:96:3
     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
     at /home/node/app/node_modules/@nestjs/passport/dist/auth.guard.js:88:83
     at MixinAuthGuard.<anonymous> (/home/node/app/node_modules/@nestjs/passport/dist/auth.guard.js:49:36)
     at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
     at fulfilled (/home/node/app/node_modules/@nestjs/passport/dist/auth.guard.js:17:58)
     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

If i commented Apple Strategy in user module, everything work fine.
I can't understand why GoogleStrategy.OAuth2Strategy.authenticate go to the appleid packages
And If I use only Google Strategy or only Apple Strategy everything works.

```
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('google'))
  @ApiOperation({ summary: 'google sign in' })
  @Get('google-sign-in')
  public async signInWithGoogle(@Req() req: any) {
    return req.user;
  }

  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('google'))
  @ApiOperation({ summary: 'google redirect' })
  @Get('auth/google/redirect')
  public async signInWithGoogleRedirect(@Req() req: any) {
    return this.userService.socialSignIn(req.user);
  }

  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('apple'))
  @ApiOperation({ summary: 'apple sign in' })
  @Get('apple-sign-in')
  public async signInWithApple(@Req() req: any) {
    return req.user;
  }

  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('apple'))
  @ApiOperation({ summary: 'apple redirect' })
  @Get('apple/redirect')
  public async signInWithAppleRedirect(@Req() req: any) {
    return this.userService.socialSignIn(req.user);
  }
```

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Profile } from 'passport';
import { Strategy, VerifyCallback } from 'passport-google-oauth20';
import { RegisteredPlatformsEnum } from 'src/_enum/registered-platforms.enum';
import { ConfigService } from '../config.services';

@Injectable()
export class GoogleStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'google') {
  constructor(configService: ConfigService) {
    super({
      clientID: configService.get('GOOGLE_AUTH_CLIENT_ID'),
      clientSecret: configService.get('GOOGLE_AUTH_CLIENT_SECRET'),
      callbackURL: configService.get('GOOGLE_AUTH_CALLBACK_URL'),
      scope: ['email', 'profile'],
    });
  }

  public async validate(
    accessToken: string,
    refreshToken: string,
    profile: Profile,
    done: VerifyCallback,
  ): Promise<any> {
    const { name, emails } = profile;
    const [userEmail] = emails;

    const user = {
      email: userEmail.value,
      name: name.givenName,
      registeredPlatform: RegisteredPlatformsEnum.GOOGLE,
      accessToken,
    };
    done(null, user);
  }
}
```

```
import path from 'path';

import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Profile } from 'passport';
import { Strategy, VerifyCallback } from 'passport-appleid';
import { RegisteredPlatformsEnum } from 'src/_enum/registered-platforms.enum';
import { ConfigService } from '../config.services';

@Injectable()
export class AppleStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'apple') {
  constructor(configService: ConfigService) {
    super({
      clientID: configService.get('APPLE_AUTH_CLIENT_ID'),
      callbackURL: configService.get('APPLE_AUTH_CALLBACK_URL'),
      teamId: configService.get('APPLE_AUTH_TEAM_ID'),
      keyIdentifier: configService.get('APPLE_AUTH_KEY_IDENTIFIER'),
      privateKeyPath: path.join(
        __dirname,
        `./AuthKey_${configService.get('APPLE_AUTH_KEY_IDENTIFIER')}.p8`,
      ),
    });
  }

  public async validate(
    accessToken: string,
    refreshToken: string,
    profile: Profile,
    done: VerifyCallback,
  ): Promise<any> {
    const { name, emails } = profile;
    const [userEmail] = emails;
    const user = {
      email: userEmail.value,
      name: name.givenName,
      registeredPlatform: RegisteredPlatformsEnum.APPLE,
      accessToken,
    };
    done(null, user);
  }
}
```

```
import { Module, forwardRef, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

import { AppModule } from '../../app.module';
import { ConfigService } from '../../services/config.services';
import { UserService } from './services/users.service';
import { UserController } from './user.controller';
import { UserEntity } from '../../model/user.entity';
import { EmailService } from '../../services/email.service';
import { UserRepository } from 'src/repositories/user.repository';
import { GoogleStrategy } from 'src/services/strategy/google-strategy';
import { AppleStrategy } from 'src/services/strategy/apple-strategy';

@Module({
  imports: [
    forwardRef(() => AppModule),
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([UserEntity, UserRepository]),
  ],
  controllers: [UserController],
  providers: [
    Logger,
    UserService,
    ConfigService,
    EmailService,

    // passport strategies
    AppleStrategy,
    GoogleStrategy,
  ],
  exports: [UserService],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

Comment: Did you import the module where `ConfigService` is defined? If you do that, you should have to export the `ConfigService` in `ConfigModule` and Import the `ConfigModule` in `UserModule`. Also , I would prefer to move the strategies to separate module such as `AuthModule`.

Comment: Try to rebuild your server. When I was working with passport in nestjs I found some really weird bugs that were almost always resolved when rebuilding.